# How to enable and configure decompilation feature in Intellij 14?

Tags: intellij-idea, decompiler

IJ 14 advertised as having automatic decompilation.  But that feature is not working for me (IJ ultimate 14.0.2)

Also - presuming that the decompilation not working can be fixed - I presume there were a way to *optionally* decompile classes? Maybe not every class do we want to have *automatically* decompiled.

*Update* the screenshot shows the Java Bytecode decompiler is enabled.

[image]

Comment: Do you have _Java Bytecode Decompiler_ enabled in Settings/Plugins?

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt  Yes, I will add screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have an old decompiler installed as well? I had the JD-IntelliJ plugin installed (it shows up in the plugin list as "Java Decompiler IntelliJ Plugin"), and did not get any files decompiled after I upgraded from IDEA 13. Once I deactivated JD-IntelliJ, however, the decompilation started working again. I guess the two decompilers got in each other's way.